# Usage of IMethodSelector in testng is not invoking the @Beforemethod and @BeforeSuite

Tags: testng

i am trying to select the tests i want to run using IMethodSelector of testng.i was successful in selecting the tests but when i run the tests,@Beforemethod @BeforeSuite is not getting executed.here is my xml where i have used IMethodselector

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="methodsuite">

<test name="test1" preserve-order="true">
  <method-selectors>
       <method-selector>
       <selector-class name="com.MethodSelector2"
         priority="-1"/>

       </method-selector>
  </method-selectors>

  <packages>
       <package name=".*"></package>
   </packages> 
 </test>



 </suite>
```

pls let me know whether implementing IMethodSelector affects @Beforemethod functionality or is there any work arounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please post a `MethodSelector2` source? Are you sure, you are not filtering configuration methods? There is a special flag to recognize if method is a config method or test method in

```
includeMethod(IMethodSelectorContext context, ITestNGMethod method, boolean isTestMethod)
```

*(last param)*

Comment: Thanks Ludwik,i was filtering configuration methods.now it is working fine

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuagle inputs ludwik